# Why is my border too wide in chrome

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to get divs with background pics to display on my web page. In IE it looks just fine, but in chrome the page looks good when it's not full screen and when you make the window full screen the border on div 2 is about 20 pixels too wide on the right side. The first div should be the size of available screen and the second 75% of that centered.
It also looks as if chrome doesn't see my 100% height on the first div.
 Here's my css style sheet:

```css
 @charset "utf-8";
 /* CSS Document */

 #main {    
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-align:center;  
    padding:40px;

    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../graphics/craig-smith-background.jpg);
}

#body {
    min-height:500px;
    width:75%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../graphics/back2.jpg); 
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    border:groove;
    border-color:#333;
    border-width:5px; (edit)
    padding:0;
}
```

I've played with padding and margins on both divs but just cant seem to figure this one out.

(edit) I should specify, there is a 20px space between the border and the picture on the right side where you can see the background pic of div 1.

Comment: Can you provide more code than just your style? Perhaps make a jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I'm sorry, what's a jsFiddle?

Comment: @CraigSmith, [jsfiddle is a site where you can create reduced test cases and easily save and share them](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing with it. I cut and past my code into the form and it starts doing weird things. There is thus far no java script or programming going on.

Comment: A visualization of your problem would be very helpful. I think most of us here lost our clairvoyant abilities after childhood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was dreamweaver not updating the local files, I changed a picture file in photoshop and saved it. Dreamweaver didn't see the file update.

Answer (score 2):

```
border:groove;
border-color:#333;
border-width:thick;
```

Don't use `thick`, specify the number of pixels you want. "2px", 5px", whatever.

Comment: I have an Idea, how do you make chrome use new style sheets. Maybe it's not loading my changes. The picture was too small to start and I re sized it. changing to 5px made no change.

Comment: @CraigSmith, Ctrl+F5 should force Chrome to ignore the cache when it refreshes.

Comment: CTRL-SHIFT-DELETE is the new CTRL-F5